# Form didn't insert data to database properly [Laravel][Eloquent]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

I have problem with my code somewhere that make my data `$request` just didn't passed to my database table (?), I'm not sure what the problem is but every time I try to submit it just redirect back to my create blade view.
But when I debug it using `dd($request->all());` it have everything it need.
My table have 5 columns, `id, book_id, member_id, user_id, borrow_date, return_date`

#### My Model

```
protected $table = "borrow";
protected $guarded = [];
public $timestamps = false;

// Relationship Book
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
}

// Relationship Member
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
}
```

#### My Create Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $book= Book::all();
    $member= Member::all();
    return view('borrow.create', compact('book', 'member'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'book_id' => 'required',
        'member_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'borrow_date' => 'required',
        'return_date' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
    Borrow::create([
        'book_id' => $request->book_id,
        'member_id' => $request->member_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'borrow_date' => $request->borrow_date,
        'return_date' => $request->return_date,
        'status' => 'borrowed',
    ]); return redirect('/borrow');
}
```

#### My Create View

```
<form action="/borrow" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select data-placeholder="Enter Book Data"
                                        data-allow-clear="1" name="book_id" id="book_id">
                                        <option></option>
                                        @foreach($book as $value)
                                        <option value="{{ $value->id }}">ISBN {{ $value->isbn }} -
                                            {{ $value->title }} ({{ $value->year }})
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Member</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select data-placeholder="Enter Member Data"
                                        data-allow-clear="1" name="member_id" id="member_id">
                                        <option></option>
                                        @foreach($member as $value)
                                        <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}
                                            @if ($value->gender == 'man')
                                            (M) -
                                            @else
                                            (W) -
                                            @endif
                                            {{ $value->phone }}
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Borrow Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="borrow_date"
                                        id="borrow_date">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Return Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="return_date"
                                        id="return_date">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                        </form>
```

#### `dd($request->all());`

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "pN3PPQGpT4jmLln59tY3HBiLj27fWgf65ioIYlv0"
  "book_id" => "99"
  "member_id" => "99"
  "borrow_date" => "2021-09-01"
  "return_date" => "2021-09-30"
]
```

Thanks! Sorry if my English and explanation is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to validate a `user_id` and a `status` presents in your `$request` but of course it doesn't.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'book_id' => 'required',
        'member_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'borrow_date' => 'required',
        'return_date' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
```

You are using `Auth::user()->id` as `user_id` and it isn't in `$request`

So, just remove `'user_id' => 'required',` from validation. You also don't have `status` in your `$request` so you need to remove it too. It should be like this;

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'book_id' => 'required',
        'member_id' => 'required',
        'borrow_date' => 'required',
        'return_date' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Comment: I tried your answer it doesn't work sir. It still not passed the data to my table

Comment: @SomeRandomCode Can you change it ad `$request->validate(['book_id' => ...])` and place a `<?php $errors->any() ? var_dump($errors->all()) : echo 'no error' ?>` to see what error redirects you to back.

Comment: Oops it worked like a charm sorry haha. I forget to delete `'status' => 'required'`. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use fillable in Peminjaman model

```
protected $fillable = [
      'id', 'book_id', 'member_id', 'user_id', 'borrow_date', 'return_date'
    ];
```

Comment: Isn't $fillable is just the same as $guarded? Oh and seems like I forgot to edit Peminjaman to english lol

Comment: $guarded you just can't mass assign it to the model but in $filable you can mass assign it to the model

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `user_id` and `status` from the validation, the request doesn't have these parameters, and you are validating them as required values.

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'book_id' => 'required',
    'member_id' => 'required',
    'borrow_date' => 'required',
    'return_date' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Yeah it worked by just deleting both of those from validation, thanks!

Comment: @SomeRandomCode then your question was wrong since you said "it have everything it need" when you `dd()`

Answer (score 0):

When using the `create()` method, you are using what is called massive assignment. As per docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment:

> ...before using the create method, you will need to specify either a
> fillable or guarded property on your model class. These properties are
> required because all Eloquent models are protected against mass
> assignment vulnerabilities by default.

Saying that, you have 2 options:

1 - Keep using `create()` method but define `fillable` property in your model

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'book_id', 'member_id', 'user_id', 'borrow_date', 'return_date'];
```

2 - Use the `save()` method with not need to define `fillable` property:

```
$borrow = new Borrow();
$borrow->book_id = $request->book_id;
$borrow->member_id = $request->member_id;
$borrow->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$borrow->borrow_date = $request->borrow_date;
$borrow->return_date = $request->return_date;
$borrow->status = 'borrowed';
$borrow->save();
```